# Cassandra: the node how to work when a new node joining ring?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, streaming

I'm a beginner in Cassandra. I want to understand the two nodes(the streaming node and joining node) how to work when a new node joins an existing cluster. Can they provide normal services to the outside?

If the service is provided normally. I assumed the joining node is nodeA, and the node where the fetching data is nodeB. That means nodeA fetch data from nodeB. Assume that the data range C is transmitted from the nodeB to the nodeA, at which time new data falling into the range C is inserted into the cluster. Is the new data written to nodeA or nodeB?

I'm using datastax community edition of cassandra, version 3.11.3.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sun your question is bit confusing .. but what I make of it is , You want to understand the process to adding new node to existing cluster.

Adding a new node to existing cluster requires cassandra.yaml properties for new node identification and communications.

Set the following properties in the cassandra.yaml and, depending on the snitch, the cassandra-topology.properties or cassandra-rackdc.properties configuration files:

**auto_bootstrap** - This property is not listed in the default cassandra.yaml configuration file, but it might have been added and set to false by other operations. If it is not defined in cassandra.yaml, Cassandra uses true as a default value. For this operation, search for this property in the cassandra.yaml file. If it is present, set it to true or delete it..

**cluster_name** - The name of the cluster the new node is joining.

**listen_address/broadcast_address** - Can usually be left blank. Otherwise, use IP address or host name that other Cassandra nodes use to connect to the new node.

**endpoint_snitch** - The snitch Cassandra uses for locating nodes and routing requests.

**num_tokens** - The number of vnodes to assign to the node. If the hardware capabilities vary among the nodes in your cluster, you can assign a proportional number of vnodes to the larger machines.

**seeds** - Determines which nodes the new node contacts to learn about the cluster and establish the gossip process. Make sure that the -seeds list includes the address of at least one node in the existing cluster.

When a new node joins a cluster using topology defined, Seed nodes starts the gossip with the new node by the time it do not communicate with the client directly. Once the gossip completes the new node is ready to take the actual data load.

Hope this helps in understanding the process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, my english is poor.

The question what i want to know is when the data of partition XXX on nodeA is streaming to nodeB, a client insert some data on this streaming partition XXX, which node will be write thoes data?nodeA or nodeB?

Comment: So it depends on the situation: 1) If Node B is newly added to existing cluster and gossip is in progress, the data write will only be on Node A , because Node B is not yet ready to handle client data. 2) If Node A and Node B are both existing node, then data write can happen on any node or both , depending on the consistency level and later replication can take place.

Comment: That's so greate for your reply. when NodeB's gossip is ready but streaming not,  then data write can happen on any node or both , depending on the consistency level and later replication can take place, and how to deal with query the streaming data.

Comment: How to deal with query the streaming data?